My car sounds like a diesel engine
I have a 2007 impala LTZ, when i turn on my car it sounds like a loud diesel engine And i barely have power to the pedal… Help Please .

Is your catalytic converter missing? Please go look.

It’s still there

My guess: the sound is knocking, aka piston knock or engine knock. It's the classic cause of diesel-like sounds coming from a standard spark/petrol engine. It's literally the piston knocking around in the cylinder. Do you have dash codes and/or have you had them read?
The actual causes of knock could be, no pun intended, manifold. In that case, no answer is possible. Check for preignition due to bad timing (are belts/chains ok/well adjusted), loss of compression due to blown head gasket or piston seals, using the wrong fuel octane, etc.

A car that becomes very loud usually has a hole or crack in an exhaust component or one of the components fell off or was cut off.
You've confirmed in a comment that your catalytic converter was not cut off and stolen. If you're going to investigate this yourself, it's best to put your car up on ramps, get under the car with the engine off and start looking for holes, cracks or broken components of the exhaust system all the way from the engine to the tailpipe.
To see the top surface of components, you can use a small mirror and a flashlight. If you can't find a defect, best to take it to a garage and let them listen to it. If they agree that it's an exhaust problem, they can put the car on a lift to find the bad component.
